# Glueing back to back and folding

Tags: print-design

Before I do this, I wanted to ask the experts on how to properly do it.  I need to glue a printed sheet to a heavier card stock paper, than I need the whole thing folder in half.  The question is do I score/fold before or after I glue the sheets together. I'm trying to avoid paper rips where the folds are.

Your help appreciated.

Comment: How heavy of a cardstock? Is it a cardstock or a matte board?

Comment: 100lb card stock matte.  The printed artwork is on a 100lb gloss book. I'm concerned about the printed artwork, not the cardstock on which it will be glued to.

Comment: I would probably score the cardstock before gluing so that the scoring wouldn't harm the printed image if the lighter sheet would not need scoring.  However, do you have an extra sheet that you could test this one?  If you do a test each way and have the results side by side, I think you will be able to tell easily which one looks better and folds easier.

Comment: You are using some kind of spay mount adhesive, I hope?

Comment: You should test it on scraps etc.: one potential problem is that as the item folds, the paper travels a slightly shorter amount and you get the tendency to either sag when folded or tear when opened. Kind of like when a car turns: the outside wheel travels farther than the inside wheel and this is why cars have a "differential." The differences are slight and probably not a problem here but if you artwork is expensive or one of a kind, you want to work out the potential kinks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Score the card stock first and be sure to work with the grain of the paper: folding one way will give you arcing pages, the other will lay much flatter.

The best tool for this is called a [bone folder](http://www.dickblick.com/products/lineco-bone-paper-folders-and-scorer/?clickTracking=true). It will not tear the paper fibers so your score is much less likely to fray.

As for the artwork, that paper has a grain as well but it may not be as evident. Try the same test and print your artwork accordingly, if possible.

When you mount the art, be very careful to apply your adhesive evenly and completely. I've had the best luck waiting until the adhesive has set to complete the fold. A few hours under pressure (heavy books) or, if you have the time, overnight will do.

Answer (score 0):

I think 100 lb cardstock is thick enough that you could glue the paper down on top of it and then score the back. Not 100% sure. If it was a regular multiply matte board I would say glue it first then score the back. With this I'm not as sure, do you really need to cut it at all? Can't you just press it in half? If you absolutely have to score or cut to get your desired result I would still glue the paper first I think.